# Parsing json data in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am trying angular for the first time and I am pretty stuck.This is the JSON data that I am receiving from an API-

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 72.85,
        "lat": 19.01
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 803,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "broken clouds",
            "icon": "04d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 301.828,
        "pressure": 1021.02,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_min": 301.828,
        "temp_max": 301.828,
        "sea_level": 1022.28,
        "grnd_level": 1021.02
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 3.52,
        "deg": 246.002
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 80
    },
    "dt": 1442131167,
    "id": 1275339,
    "name": "Mumbai",
    "cod": 200
}
```

This is my function in controller-

```
(
function () {
    var app=angular.module("weather",[]);
    var query="";
    app.controller("search",function(){
        query="mumbai";

    });

    app.controller("result",['$http','$scope',function($http,$scope){

        var city=query;
        $http({
            url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
            method:'GET',
            params:{q:city}
        }).then(function (response) {

            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.name);

        },function (response){
            //error message
        });


    }]);
}
)();
```

Following are the console messages-

[image]

So I am not able to understand that if `console.log(response)` is showing `Object` then why `console.log(response.name)` is showing undefined instead of "Mumbai".

Suggest a possible solution.

EDIT -
Solution found :
Console.log(response.data.name);
seen the docs

Comment: See what's in `response.data`

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos got it .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you would realize that

> The response object has these properties:
>
> data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
>
> status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
>
> headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
>
> config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
>
> statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

The answer to your question in the comment is also in the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> ### Default Transformations
>
> The $httpProvider provider and $http service
>   expose defaults.transformRequest and defaults.transformResponse
>   properties. If a request does not provide its own transformations then
>   these will be applied.
>
> You can augment or replace the default transformations by modifying
>   these properties by adding to or replacing the array.
>
> Angular provides the following default transformations:
>
> Request transformations ($httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest and
>   $http.defaults.transformRequest):
>
> **If the data property of the request configuration object contains an
>   object, serialize it into JSON format.**
>
> Response transformations
>   ($httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse and
>   $http.defaults.transformResponse):
>
> If XSRF prefix is detected, strip it (see Security Considerations
>   section below). If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a
>   JSON parser.

Comment: Thanks got it. just one thing can we specify any parameter to tell angular that the data received will be json?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse() for de-serializing JSON object you got from API

```
 $http({
        url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
        method:'GET',
        params:{q:city}
    }).then(function (response) {
        var response=JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.name);

    },function (response){
        //error message
    });


}]);
```